# Stable Diffusion Error: Couldn't install torch / No matching distribution found for torch==1.12.1+cu113

Tags: python, pytorch, stable-diffusion

I am trying to install locally Stable Diffusion. I follow the presented steps but when I get to the last one "run webui-use file" it opens the terminal and it's saying "Press any key to continue...". If I do so the terminal instantly closes.
I went to the SB folder, right-clicked open in the terminal and used ./webui-user to run the file. The terminal does not longer close but nothing is happening and I get those two errors:

`Couldn't install torch`,

`No matching distribution found for torch==1.12.1+cu113`

I've researched online and I've tried installing the torch version from the error, also I tried `pip install --user pipenv==2022.1.8` but I get the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar error. What solved the issue was, I installed the 32 bit version of python. I uninstalled and installed the x86-64 bit version. And everything installed just fine. I have version 3.8 installed as i have found out it is the most stable version.

I downloaded the 64 bit installer from here
[python 3.8](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-380/)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem, found out that I was using python 3.11, instead of the version from instructions - Python 3.10.6; You can uninstall other versions from Programs and Features/ edit env vars

Comment: I have tried. when I install python it's saying that 3.10.6 is installing

Comment: just check the python version, you are right. I am using 3.11

Comment: Apparently I have both versions pf py. I uninstalled the 3.11 version and now I get this error `No Python at '"C:\Python311\python.exe'`

Comment: restart the SD web ui cmd after changing the python version; i went through the same process, installing 3.11, then installing 3.10, then uninstall 3.11; checked version and then user env variables, restarted cmd and it worked; try a PC restart too

Comment: I ran into the same problem and I didn't believe I used the wrong python version, but it turns out I was specifying python 3.6.10 instead of 3.10.6

Answer (score 1):

if has some problems with a python, remove venv folder, this will be generated again by script, because if you have another version to python this config files will be replaced with your paths, everything if you change a python version, don't forgot delete this folder venv.

Answer (score 0):

`conda config --append channels pytorch`